# Package substrate layer definition: 4-2-4

Tags: pcb

Where can I find the definition of this "4-2-4" naming convention of package substrate?

What does each number stand for in this string?

Thanks,
Neo

[image]

Comment: Its shown in the little green diagram - 4 copper layers at small spacing, 2 copper layers with the thicker core, then another 4 layers at small spacing.

Comment: Understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its shown in the little green diagram - 4 copper layers at small spacing, 2 copper layers with the thicker core, then another 4 layers at small spacing.

Thanks to Kartman.